# Mac OS X 10.6 Kerberos authentication for network shares

Tags: mac, networking, osx-snow-leopard, kerberos

I'm on a kerberos network, and I want to add someone's network kerberos username to one of my shared folders on my mac.

On windows, assuming you were on the same domain, you could just type in the name, click "Check Names" or whatever, and it would autocomplete to the kerberos identity found on the network, and that person could log in with their kerberos user/pass without me knowing their pass.

There has to be a way to do the same on the mac.

Comment: Are you looking to share a folder on your computer or on the network with another domain user?

Comment: yes. Both computers are on the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I am guessing the folder is on your computer, and not on a share.

1. First, you will need to turn sharing on in the System Preferences.
2. Then set it as AFP if you are both on a Mac, or SMB if the other user is on a PC.
3. Choose the folder you want to share.
4. Now, click the + next to users.
5. You should see the domain as an option on the left, highlight it and search for the user
   [image]
6. Select the user and give the user the permissions you would like them to have on the folder
7. Give the user the address to your now set up share.

If you are not seeing the domain as an option on the left, it's time to search for information on Directory Services.

Comment: How do I search for the domain on Directory Services?

Comment: Directory Services has been moved to /System/Library/CoreServices/Directory Utility.  Check with your network admin on how to add your LDAP to this for contacts searching.